# Unix SSH : Find files with different path on two servers

Tags: unix, ssh

I have server A & Server B . I want to file find command on both server but with different path .

**Currently i created below code to do so :**

```
dir1=( $DATA_DIR/sdfgv  $DATA_DIR/1wefgg $DATA_DIR/3fdsevg );
dir2=( $DATA_DIR/asdf  $DATA_DIR/sdfewfT $DATA_DIR/efergvfw );

timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S);
report_name=Audit_Report_${timestamp}.txt

uname=xyz
server=( serv1 serv2);

for j in ${server[@]}; 
do {
if [ "$j" == "serv1 " ]
then
for i in ${dir1[@]}; 
do { 
Size=`ssh -q $uname@$j "find $i -type f -mtime +1 -name '*.gz' -printf '%s + ' | dc -e0 -f- -ep"`; 
echo " $j        $i                $Size "
}  
done 
else 
for i in ${dir2[@]}; 
do { 
Size=`ssh -q $uname@$j "find $i -type f -mtime +1 -name '*.gz' -exec du -k {} \; | awk '{ total += $ 1} END{print total/1024;}'"`; 
echo " $j        $i                $Size "
}
done
fi
}
done
```

This code works pretty good but i want something that can be generic without if else on server name .

I dont want to use if else for server name .

Both server have different directory path to search for

Please come up with some suggestions .

Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

Bash functions would help.  Perhaps one for determining which directory to use for which server, and then one for executing the find command.  Something like this (pseudo-code, untested):

```js
getDirs() {
  if [ $1 == 'server1' ]; then
    echo $dir1
  fi
  if [ $1 == 'server2' ]; then
    echo $dir2
  fi
}

findFiles() {
  local srv=$1
  shift
  local dir=$1
  shift
  local findArgs=$@

  echo $(ssh -q $uname@$srv "find $dir $findArgs")
}

for srv in ${server[@]};
do
  dirs=$(getDirs $srv)
  for d in $dirs
  do
    findFiles $srv $d -type f -mtime +1 -name '*.gz'
  done
done
```

Your sample does different things with the find results, so you will still need to add logic to handle that (could just be an `if` statement inside the loops maybe..)